# sending data from action method to sql server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this action method

```
 [HttpPost]
   public void Test(HttpPostedFileBase file)
   {
    byte[] image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);
   }
```

I want to send byte array from this action method to sql server database in a column of table.... How can I do this ?

Comment: use varbinary type in database column

Comment: yes I have already done that. You did not get my question. I do not know how to create database object inside action method that will save this byte array into sql server....

Comment: Same way you do it in any other .NET program - just because the method has a specific signature and runs in a specific runtime does not change the ADO.NET code at all, you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyImage
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}


   [HttpPost]
   public void Test(HttpPostedFileBase file)
   {
    byte[] image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);
    var i = new MyImage { Image = image };
    dbcontext.MyEntity.Add(i);
    dbcontext.SaveChanges(); 
   }
```

Just save the byte array in your entity property, and it should work.

Comment: [HttpPost]

   public void Test(HttpPostedFileBase file)

   {
       UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

       byte[] image = new byte[file.ContentLength];

       file.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);

       
       CrimeReport i = new CrimeReport { ImageId=1, ImageName="Anjli", ImageContent = image , Active=true};

       db.CrimeReports.Add(i);
       db.SaveChanges();
   }

Comment: I was trying to use this but its giving me error on db.CrimeReports.Add(i) line, an exception occurs

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: this is exception occured when your model is not valid against database, please dig into internal exceptions, code has nothing to with that....if ImageId is primary key and set autoIncrement than make it 0...